# How i will make a JOIN in generator.yml file?

Tags: php, join, symfony1

I have a **generator.yml** file in the backend folder, the config in the generator file is:

generator:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  list:
    title: Send Email
    display: [subject, Body, email_Type_id, user_id]

  filter:
    display: [id, subject, Body, email, user_id]
```

The `email_id` and `user_id` was `foreign key` in the *message table* and `primary key` in *(email table, user table)*, and it show in the fields the id but i want to let it show the user of the id that related to the message so i need to JOIN! how i will make it?

> subject->Hello, Body->Hi iam.., Email_Type_id->1,   User_id->8

In the `email_id` and `user_id` i want to show the `user_name` with the *id* 5 and in the `email_type_id` I want to show the type with *id* 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it is add the join in your model in a new getter and reference the getter in your generator config.

```
public function getUser_name()
{
    return $this->User->getName();
}

public function getEmail_type_name()
{
    return $this->Email_type->getName();
}
```

Then in your generator:

```
display: [subject, body, email_type_name, user_name]
```